# How to have stepper motor compass pass through 360 degree

Tags: arduino

Hello I am building a wet compass for a flight simulator. I currently have a stepper motor functioning well with the simulator but at the point of crossing 360 to 0 degrees the stepper does a full reverse 360 to get into position.

My question... can anyone please assist me in creating code that makes the linear cross from 360 to 0 work in both directions.

The simulator feeds a Float Val that is a degree out of 360 eg. 172.13. My stepper has 4076 steps per full revolution. You will see the math in the code below. I am using the AccelStepper library.

```
void ProgOut(byte id, float val) {
switch (1) {
case 1:  

if (val)
        { stepper1.moveTo(val * 11.3222222);         } 
         
        stepper1.run(); 

break; }}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
void ProgOut(byte id, float val) {
switch (1) { 
case 1:  
if ( stepper1.distanceToGo () >= 4064){
          stepper1.moveTo(4076);
          stepper1.setCurrentPosition(0);
}
    else if (val)
        { 
                
                stepper1.moveTo(val * 11.3222222);         
        } 
         
        stepper1.run(); 

break; }}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

if you already found out the resolution of your motor stepper, just do a simple conversion task:

```
const float resolution  = xx.xx; // put your step resolution here
int step_degree(float desired_degree){
    return (desired_degree/resolution);}
```

This can be use by calling

```
stepper.step(step_degree(40)); //rotate 40 degree.
```

So in your case if you want it to cross over smoothly from 360 to 0, just pass an angle that is greater than 360 in the step degree.